# How can I loop the search function?

Tags: python, list, function, sqlite, search

I have sqlite db table with id and codename colums.

```
1 aaaa1223
2 bbbb2321321
3 cccc23112
```

and I have txt file:

```
aaaa Result1
bbbb Result2
cccc Result3
....
```

How can I loop the search function?

Now my result print only:

```
aaaa = Result1
```

But I need print:

```
aaaa = Result1
bbbb = Result2
cccc = Result3




import sqlite3
import codecs

con = sqlite3.connect('database.dbl')

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT id,codename FROM data")

rows = cur.fetchall()

filetxt = codecs.open("codenamefile.txt", 'r', 'utf-8')

def ScanData(f):
    for line in filetxt:
        if f==line.split("      ")[0]:
            print (codenamec+" = "+line.split("       ")[1])
    return

for row in rows:
    codename=row[1]
    codenamec=codename[:4]
    ScanData(codenamec)
```

Comment: How is `aaaa = Result1`?  Could you explain your output? How is this output related to sqlite db table?

Comment: The expected result might be created just be replacing `' '` by `' = '`. I probably do not understand the question...

Comment: @Austin codename=aaaa, in database it`s id=1, ScanData search codename==aaaa in lines in codename.txt, and print split phrase "Result1".

Answer (score 0):

You can read your file contents into a dictionary, and then use `re` with the results from the database:

```
import sqlite3
file_data = dict(i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('filename.txt'))
data = sqlite3.connect('filename.db').cursor().execute('SELECT * FROM table')
final_results = dict((lambda x:[x, file_data[x]])(re.findall('[a-z]+', i)[0]) for _, i in data)
```

Output:

```
{'aaaa': 'Result1', 'bbbb': 'Result2', 'cccc': 'Result3'}
```

Comment: I just enter open/close filetxt intro ScanData function